# Recursion in Java- Replicating String

Tags: java, string, recursion, replication

I am attempting to replicate a string using recursion and I am attempting to get O(log n) complexity. I have written the following code but it only works for powers of 2.

I tried but I couldn't solve it for all numbers. Any suggestions?

```
public class Main {
    public static int i=1;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // write your code here
        String stringnum="a";
        System.out.println("Final ="+Print(stringnum,8,stringnum));
    }

    public static String Print(String string,int num, String originalString){

        if(num<=1){
            System.out.println("base case called"+ string);
            return string;
        }
        else{
            string= string+string;
            System.out.println(i+""+string);
            i++;
            return Print(string,num/2,originalString);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of:

```
public static String Repeat(String string, int num) {
    if (num <= 0)
        return "";
    if (num == 1)
        return string;

    return Repeat(string + string, num / 2) +
        Repeat(string, num % 2);
}
```

EDIT: Some hints to make your question more easy to understand

I guess you meant for your method to be called something like `Repeat` and not `Print`. To further confused, a lot of `System.out.println` statements are there I am guessing for debugging purposes, right?

I changed the method name in my answer to `Repeat` to make its purpose obvious to the viewer.

Comment: @susheelbhargavk you should accept the answer if it worked.